# Image quality issues with generateThumbnail

Tags: php, azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

Testing the `generateThumbnail` call of the Azure Computer Vision API from PHP. I have been able to get it to operate, but the images being saved locally are very, very poor quality. Highly pixelated, very blurry, etc. They look nothing like the examples presented at https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/computer-vision-api/documentation#Thumbnails

Is this an issue with the image processing on the server side, or possibly a degradation issue occurring locally during the file save process? I'm having trouble determining where to start on this one.

This seems to be the same follow-up question asked here:
[Generate thumbnail in php, posting to Azure Computer Vision API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985715/generate-thumbnail-in-php-posting-to-azure-computer-vision-api)

Source image dimensions are 542x1714. Trying to create 115x115 thumbnail.

Code at the moment.  Have tried it with smartCropping set to both True and False.

```
        $posturl = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/generateThumbnail';
        $posturl = add_query_arg( array( 'width' => $max_w, 'height' => $max_h, 'smartCropping' => true), $posturl);

        $request = wp_remote_post( $posturl, array( 'headers' => array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream', 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' ), 'body' => file_get_contents( $this->file ) ) );

        if ( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
            return null;
        } else {
            $resized = @imagecreatefromstring( $request['body'] );
        }
```

Comment: without actual code (you are using) or knowing what the image base resolutions are, is pretty hard to say. Check your server settings.

Comment: Added code and image resolutions

Comment: Did some tinkering with saving the '$request['body']' directly to file rather than running it through `imagecreatefromstring` and still seeing the same degradation of image quality.

Comment: I honestly don't know Patrick, wish I could help out more. See what `phpinfo()` shows if there's anything related to a default image quality setting.